# TypeError: Invalid implicit conversion from address to address payable requested

Tags: tokens, erc-721, openzeppelin, mint, royalties

What's up everyone!

I'm working on adding royalties to my ERC-721 smart contract.
My goal is to give royalties back to the artist whenever someone mints a new token or transfers a token.

However, now I'm getting an error when I try to migrate my contract.

```
TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from address to address payable requested

           setRoyalties(_tokenIdTracker.current(),devAddress,2000);
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

**This is my contract**

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "./@rarible/royalties/contracts/impl/RoyaltiesV2Impl.sol";
import "./@rarible/royalties/contracts/LibPart.sol";
import "./@rarible/royalties/contracts/LibRoyaltiesV2.sol";

contract EpicTest is ERC721, Ownable, RoyaltiesV2Impl {
    
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdTracker;

    uint256 public constant MAX_ELEMENTS = 1000;
    bytes4 private constant _INTERFACE_ID_ERC2981 = 0x2a55205a;
    uint256 private startSales = 1634124766;
    
    address public constant artistAddress = 0xcBC0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0;

    constructor() ERC721("EpicTest", "ET") {}
    
    function mint(address _to) public onlyOwner {
        super._mint(_to, _tokenIdTracker.current());
        setRoyalties(_tokenIdTracker.current(),artistAddress,2000);
        _tokenIdTracker.increment();
    }


    function setRoyalties(uint _tokenId, address payable _royaltiesReceipientAddress, uint96 _percentageBasisPoints) public onlyOwner {
        LibPart.Part[] memory _royalties = new LibPart.Part[](1);
        _royalties[0].value = _percentageBasisPoints;
        _royalties[0].account = _royaltiesReceipientAddress;
        _saveRoyalties(_tokenId, _royalties);
    }

    function royaltyInfo(uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _salePrice) external view returns (address receiver, uint256 royaltyAmount) {
        LibPart.Part[] memory _royalties = royalties[_tokenId];
        if(_royalties.length > 0) {
            return (_royalties[0].account, (_salePrice * _royalties[0].value)/10000);
        }
        return (address(0), 0);
    }
    

}
```

I was using the EpicEagles contract as reference [smart contract code](https://etherscan.io/address/0x395fc9db003e58b804188155dc7e0e609a062f61#code), and they seem to be doing something similar, I might be missing a step. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

*What i've tried:*

- address payable constant artistAddress = 0xcBC0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0;

Comment: Maybe `setRoyalties(_tokenIdTracker.current(),payable(devAddress),2000);` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call is sending `devAddress` to the `setRoyalties` method which expects in its place `address payable _royaltiesReceipientAddress`. Since its expecting a paybale address on the function you have to convert it before it goes to the method, you can do so by casting it as `payable` while calling the function:

`setRoyalties(_tokenIdTracker.current(),payable(devAddress),2000);`